# Gtest returns SegFault when accessing variable in TEST_F

Tags: c++, unit-testing, segmentation-fault, googletest

I am a beginner for Gtest and facing segmentation fault when accessing a class variable inside TEST_F. Below is the snippet of my code, kindly help in pointing the reason behind this behavior.

main.cpp

```
#include <Foo.h>
#include "gtest/gtest.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  InitalRegister();
  ::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
  int rc = RUN_ALL_TESTS();
  return rc;
}
```

Foo.h

```
void InitalRegister();
class TestFoo // Required for registration
{
  //Do nothing
};
```

Foo.cpp

```
#include "gtest/gtest.h"
#include <Foo.h>
#include <Bar.h>

void InitalRegister()
{
  //Doing few registration
}

Bar* newBar;
void Bar_called_init(void *inValue) // will be called as part of InitialRegsiter and inValue will be holding a valid value
{
  newBar = (Bar)*inValue;
}

class UnitTestFoo : public::testing::Test
{
  public:
    Bar* inValue;
    Bar* GetValue();
  protected:
  virtual void SetUp() override
  {
    inValue = GetValue();//able to access inValue here
  }
};

Bar* UnitTestFoo::GetValue()
{
  inValue = newBar;
}

TEST_F(UnitTestFoo, Foo1)
{
 if (inValue != NULL) // Getting segfault when accessing inValue here
 {
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are at least 2 major issues with the code you presented (and I don't see `Bar.h`):

- `GetValue` doesn't return any value while it should return `Bar*`, please update your code to sth like:

  ```
    Bar* UnitTestFoo::GetValue()
    {
      inValue = newBar;
      return inValue;
    }
  ```
- `Bar_called_init` tries to dereference `void*` pointer which should yield a compilation error, please update your code to sth like:

  ```
    void Bar_called_init(void *inValue)
    {
      newBar = (Bar*)inValue;
    }
  ```

Does you code compile on your machine? With these two fixes I was able to see the test passing:

```
[ RUN      ] UnitTestFoo.Foo1
[       OK ] UnitTestFoo.Foo1 (0 ms)
```